# PHP in python through bash

Tags: php, python, bash

As I am messing around with Python, I wanted to write an application that would have its own web server. I am currently using a written code from this website for http server: [Python Web Server](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php) and this is the [direct link of the script](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/img/pythonweb.zip)

This script can handle html but I wanted to add php to it too. Since I know that in Ubuntu I can run php commands within the terminal, I wanted to implement the same logic to this script.

I added these lines:

```
import os
os.system('php '+filepath)
```

However my plan didn't go as well as planned... The "`<? echo 'hello world'; ?>`" that was in my test.php echoed the string to the terminal that ran the webserver.py and it only returned the output message "`0`" to the web browser.

Is there a way to capture the output of the php file into a string in bash so that I can make the python webserver script output that string with `os.system` ?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: oh, you are really far away from doing this. Read a little bit about wsgi, cgi and web servers first.

Comment: I thought so at first too but when I did it like Adam Wagner said it worked like a charm! :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getoutput` from the `commands` package for this simple case.

```
from commands import getoutput

response = getoutput('php myscript.php')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should eschew the use of os.system() in favor of the more modern [subprocess module.](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

You might especially look at popen.communicate().